# Is there a way to update context's state concurrently from multiple components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a screen to display products available for sale. At the same time, each product would show its favorited status by the logged in user. To do this, each product loads its corresponding favoriteItem data from the backend.
If successful, 2 things happen:
1-the data is added to an array which is a state in a global context
2- the color of the heart is updated based on the state(by finding it)

The problem is the state always starts with the initial value(empty) before subsequent data is added to the array. As a result, the state ends up with only one item.

Below is some code for demo(I've simplified and omitted code for this demo):

```
// AccountProvider.tsx
const AccountProvider = ({children}: Props)=> {
   const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]) 
   
   const loadFavoriteItemForProduct = async (productId: string)=> {
       
      const favoriteItem = await apiManager.getFavoriteItem(productId)
      // favorites always resets to its inital  value when this function is called
      setFavorites([...favorites, favoriteItem])
   }

   const account: Account = {
       loadFavoriteItemForProduct
   }

 return (
    <AccountContext.Provider value={account}>
      {children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
}

// ProductCard.tsx
// On mount, each productCard loads its favoriteItem data.

const ProductCard = ({product}: ProductCardProps) => {
    
    const userAccount = useContext(AccountContext)
    
    useEffect(()=>{
       // loads product's favoritedItem. Favorites ought to contain
       // as many favoriteItems in the backend. But, favorites is reinitialized before
       // the new item is added. As a result, favorites contain only the favoriteItem of                //the last ProductCard. See Screenshot attached 

       userAccount.loadFavoritedItemForProduct(product.productId)
    }, []) 

    return (
       <div>product.title</div>
    ) 
}

// Products.tsx

const Products = () => {
     const explore = useContext(ExploreContext)
     
     return (
        <div>
           {explore.products.map(product => <ProductCard product={product} />)} 
       </div>
     )
}

// index.tsx
...
   
   <AccountProvider>
     <ExploreProvider>
         <Products />
      </ExploreProvider>
   </AccountProvider>

...
```

I'm just trying to use Context to model the userAccount which contains the users favorites. favorites ought to contain all favoriteItem data from the backend[image: favorites state ought to contain favoriteItem data for two products but contains only one. Favorites was reinitailized before the second data could be added]. But it only contains that of the last product. See attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing an updater function to `setFavorites`.

`setFavorites((favorites) => [...favorites, favoriteItem]);`

React Docs:
https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state